# QString and german umlauts

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I am working with C++ and QT and have a problem with german umlauts. I have a QString like "wir sind müde" and want to change it to "wir sind m&uuml;de" in order to show it correctly in a QTextBrowser.

I tried to do it like this:

```
s = s.replace( QChar('ü'), QString("&uuml;"));
```

But it does not work.

Also

```
 s = s.replace( QChar('\u00fc'), QString("&uuml;"))
```

does not work.

When I iterate through all characters of the string in a loop, the 'ü' are two characters.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Actually, what's is the difference in your strings before and after replacing? "wir sind müde" and "wir sind müde"

Comment: I corrected it to "wir sind m'&uuml';de" (without ' '). The site convertet it to ü because it's the html representation for ü.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QStrings are UTF-16.

> QString stores a string of 16-bit QChars, where each QChar corresponds one Unicode 4.0 character. (Unicode characters with code values above 65535 are stored using surrogate pairs, i.e., two consecutive QChars.)

So try

```
//if ü is utf-16, see your fileencoding to know this
s.replace("ü", "&uuml;")

//if ü if you are inputting it from an editor in latin1 mode
s.replace(QString::fromLatin1("ü"), "&uuml;");
s.replace(QString::fromUtf8("ü"), "&uuml;"); //there are a bunch of others, just make sure to select the correct one
```

Comment: Thank you! s.replace(QString::fromLatin1("ü"), "&uuml;"); works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different representations of `ü` in Unicode:

- The single point `00FC` (LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS)
- The sequence `0075` (LATIN SMALL LETTER U) `0308` (COMBINING DIAERESIS)

You should check for both.

Comment: No need to. Internally it is stored as two distinct code points. See the quote on my post. "Stored as surrogate pairs"

Comment: @RedX: that refers to code points above 65535, which doesn't apply here. The documentation doesn't specify how accented characters are represented - presumably, that will depend on how the string was generated.

Comment: You are right. If he were unsure, he could get a normalized version with `normalize()`.